# How to take the tensor product over multiple vectors

Tags: matrices, vectors

I encounter a math equation that seems to take the tensor product over a set. More specifically, given a set of vector $S = [\psi_{x^1},\psi_{x^2},...,\psi_{x^n}]$, the equation says:

[image]

I understand how to take the pairwise tensor product, but I don't understand how to take tensor product over a set of vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $n=4$, as an example. Then $$\psi_{x_S} = \psi_{x^1}\otimes\psi_{x^2}\otimes\psi_{x^3}\otimes\psi_{x^4}.$$You can define recursively for higher $n$ if you want, eg.$$\psi_{x_{S+1}} = \psi_{x_S}\otimes\psi_{x^{n{+}1}}.$$The tensor product is associative, so it makes sense to define in terms of pairwise tensor products this way.

Comment: Thanks, my main question is, say 1 is n by 1, then  1⊗2 yield n x n matrix, and what would a nxn matrix ⊗ an nx1 vector looks like

Comment: @FoolBoy, I find it easiest to think in terms of components. Then your vector is $v_i$, your matrix $M_{ij}$ and their tensor product is a rank 3 tensor, with components $T_{ijk}=M_{ij}v_k$. So you can see that when you fix $k$ you get an $n\times n$ matrix for each $k$, and so you have an object with dimensions $n\times n \times n$. It's like a 3d array of numbers made of $n$ matrices stacked on top of each other. If you're happy with my answer, you can accept it by pressing the tick next to the voting arrows.